# Fetch data from messaging app to my android app

Tags: android, mysql

How can I fetch data from messaging app to my android app?
Whenever I receive any message stating "credited" or "debited", it should fetch into my android app automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You have to register a BroadcastReciever in the manifest file with an intent-filter to receiving SMS. BroadcastReceiver receives the intent-filtered SMS messages. onReceive, you can extract the SMS message from the Intent. You can find a good tutorial in the following link

http://javapapers.com/android/android-receive-sms-tutorial/

Comment: Thank you for your advice and the tutorial. I am just curious to know if i can just add read permission in manifest and fetch the data when the message consists of text such as "credited" or "debited".?

Comment: You can extract the SMS message from the Intent and check it contains "credited" or "debited"  and do your processing.

Answer (score 0):

For getting notification of the change you can use push notification and now a days [Google Cloud Messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/) is in trend for small aplications